# Transfer files FROM Ubuntu TO Windows XP over wireless

Tags: wireless, windows

I have a wireless network configured at home. I have a Windows XP laptop and a Ubuntu 12.04.1 laptop.  I have shared a folder on both computers.  I am able to read/write files from my Windows computer to my Ubuntu computer.  I am not able to access the shared folder on my Windows computer from my Ubuntu computer.

When I click on the "Browse Network -> Windows Network" my wireless appears as a folder.  If I click on that it attempts to open but eventually fails.  I expected to eventually see a connection to the Windows computer.  Instead I get a message "Unable to mount location" with a sub-message "Failed to retrieve share list from server".

I suspect this is something rather simple.  I am not a Ubuntu expert by any means.  I am in the process of switching from Windows to Ubuntu as much as possible (I think I'll always have to maintain a Windows presence for my wife).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Nitroshare!

Get it from [here](http://nitroshare.net) for your Windows machine.

For Ubuntu, the easiest way to install is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/nitroshare-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nitroshare
```

Comment: This looks interesting.  I was hoping there would be something I could change in a setting somewhere which would allow me to move the files between computers directly.  I am able to move files directly from my Windows machine to the Ubuntu machine.

Nevertheless, if nitroshare (or something similar) is necessary then I guess that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: it's not necessary, but the big advantage is that you will be able to use it regardless of the other machine's os. otherwise there's of course SAMBA. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba which you are apparently using now. Check again if you made any mistake and try to give a better explanation of what you did so far.

Comment: In Nautilus I select 'Browse Network'.  This shows a folder called 'Windows Network'.  In there I see 'MSHOME' which is the name of my network workgroup.  That ultimately results in the message:

Unable to mount location
Failed to retrieve share list from server

I am using Samba.

If I explore the network from my Windows machines they (3) can all see each other, share directories and printers.  From the Ubuntu machine I am unable to see any of the Windows machines or the shared printers.